# Server side Timer class in Asp.Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer

I am trying to implement a timer control within a static class in Asp.Net MVC which get initialized in static constructor. I am expecting that this Timer object should be ticking every 20 sec and should t_Elapsed method in which I want to do some operation. 
But once I close the browser, Timer object get Disposed and does not work.

Can anyone suggest a way where this timer should keep running even if no one is using the website..

//This is global variable in the static class

```
static System.Timers.Timer t = null;
```

//this code is executed in static constructor of the same static class

```
t = new System.Timers.Timer(20000); //Every 20 seconds
t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
t.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: In general a web application isn't a great way to have a background process constantly running on the server.  A Windows Service seems more appropriate for that.

Comment: I agree. This is not an ideal situation. I've actually never seen this done successfully. You can use a scheduled task from the OS, a service, or something like that to achieve the desired functionality though.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/